# jquery.mb.YTPlayer how to add a url redirect triggered by the end of the video

Tags: jquery, css, html

New to coding, I have tried inserting various HTML5 code such as:   function redirect() {   document.location="index_2.html";  } 

Your browser cannot display the video element.

This works for the browser player so I tried adding element of the above to the following code:

function redirect() { document.location="index.html";  }

```
<a id="bg-video" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDvBwPzJ7dY',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:false, startAt:0, showControls:false, loop:false, onended:redirect()"}" data-poster="images/bg.jpg">youtube</a>
<div id="bg-video-controls">
    <a id="bg-video-volume" class="fa fa-volume-off" href="#" title="Unmute">&nbsp;</a>
    <a id="bg-video-play" class="fa fa-pause" href="#" title="Pause">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<!-- End YouTube background video -->
```

I can get the redirect to work but then the video will not play.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after looking at it and struggling until I was near insanity with frustration, then, I looked at my free template and realized the letters, numbers are part of a YouTube address.

You did the same thing I did - put in the whole address - but, that's what screwed us up. This is what the before and after (wrong and right) look like using your example: 
{videoURL:'**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDvBwPzJ7dY'**,containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:false, startAt:0, showControls:false, loop:false, onended:redirect()"}" data-poster="images/bg.jpg">youtube
  ***This is the wrong way!!!***

Here is the correct url:
{videoURL:'***tDvBwPzJ7dY***',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:false, startAt:0, showControls:false, loop:false, onended:redirect()"}" data-poster="images/bg.jpg">youtube

Remove (delete) ***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*** and only put   ***tDvBwPzJ7dY***. Your video will work.